# Returning the correct type from Promise.all in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-promise

I am making 2 API requests in a promise.all() statement followed by a .then() statement to manipulate the data to fit an expected result type. The function works when I launch API requests separately using async/await but using promise.all results in the returned array being of type void. How can I change the response to infer the correct type?

This returns the correct type

```
async function getUsers() {
    const users = await axios.get<User[]>("serverURL/users");
    const data = await axios.get<
        Array<{ name: string; data: number }>
    >("serverURL/data");

    const userData = users.data.map(user => {
        return {
            //logic to manipulate userData
        };
    });

    return userData;
}
```

promise.all version returns type 'void | type assigned to.then()' which gets the correct data and I can console.log the result to confirm that it follows the expected structure. However the compiler rejects it with the error:

```
Type 'void | UserData[]' is not assignable to type 'UserData[]'.
```

```
const getUsers = async () => {
    return Promise
        .all([
            axios.get<User[]>("serverURL/users"),
            axios.get<Array<{ name: string; data: number }>>("serverURL/data")
        ])
        .then <UserData[]>(res => {
            const userData = res[0].map(user => {
                return {
                    //logic to manipulate userData
                };
            });
            return userData;
        })
        .catch(console.error)
}
```

I have tried using `promise.all<any>()` and various other tips I've read but the documentation regarding promise.all with Typescript is quite sparse. I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction or tell me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In you second `getUsers` function im not sure how you are accessing `users`. You need to destructure the `res` array to be able to access the users as the first element but Im not seeing.

Comment: @Brenden Yes thanks I missed that while obfuscating the variables because I can't post it directly. I have corrected it but the data from the API is being accessed correctly. It is an issue with the way that Promise.all returns types, not the map function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is the catch. When you catch/handle a promise rejection you are returning nothing/void causing the promise to be fulfilled. `console.error` returns void, but does not rethrow. Therefore your return will return a `UserData | void`. Throwing after the catch should fix this.

Comment: Thank you, appreciate you taking the time to look at this.